# Is it possibile to use a CAN transceiver to send RS485 data?

Tags: can, rs485

Looking at the signal ranges I'm not sure if I can use a CAN transceiver (*not* controller!) to send data to a single RS485 device.

Comment: I believe you can, but why would you want to? RS-485 transceivers tend to be more available with better specs I find.

Comment: Is it possible for a VW Golf to drive from Toronto to Timbuktu?

Comment: Well, I guess you might want to if you are making something that you want to connect up to either CAN or RS-485 but don't have enough room to squeeze in a second transceiver.

Comment: @DKNguyen, it'easier :) I have a development board with a CAN transceiver. In my own final board I will put of course an RS-485 tranceiver. In the meanwhile I wonder if I can test my firmware with CAN, even if the target device is RS-485 compliant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the CAN recessive state, the differential voltage can be zero. This is not a valid RS-485 signal level.

However, many RS-485 receivers have built-in fail-safe logic that interprets an undriven bus as logic one, and a bus without such logic is supposed to have fail-safe biasing resistors with the same effect. So if you wire the bus so that the CAN dominant state (CANH > CANL) corresponds to RS-485 logical zero (A < B), then it might actually work.